# Why SQL Server add Sort after Merge Join

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Could someone explain why SQL server add `Sort` after `Merge Join`, that returns already return sorted output by columns in `Sort` operator.

Here is query to reproduce.
Initial data:

```
DROP TABLE Temp1;
CREATE TABLE Temp1 (
    Id1 INT,
    Id2 INT,
    Value1 INT
)
GO

DROP TABLE Temp2;
CREATE TABLE Temp2 (
    Id1 INT,
    Id2 INT,
    Value2 INT
)
GO

DECLARE @I AS INT;
SET @I = 0

WHILE @I < 10000
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Temp1 (Id1, Id2, Value1) VALUES (@I, @I + 1, @I)
    INSERT INTO Temp2 (Id1, Id2, Value2) VALUES (@I, @I + 1, @I)

    SET @I = @I + 1
END
GO

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX PK_Temp1 ON Temp1 (Id1, Id2)
GO

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX PK_Temp2 ON Temp2 (Id1, Id2)
GO
```

And actual query:

```
SELECT
    t1.Id1,
    t1.Id2,
    t1.Value1,
    MAX(t1.Value1) OVER (PARTITION BY t1.Id1) AS MaxValue1,
    t2.Value2
FROM Temp1 t1
LEFT JOIN Temp2 t2 ON t1.Id1 = t2.Id1 AND t1.Id2 = t2.Id2
```

And the most suspicious behavior is `Sort` after `Merge Join`.

[Here](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=H1uxG7Ue4) is complete plan (including XML):

[image: Plan with sort oprator]

If I add `ORDER BY` at the end of query without `MAX`:

```
SELECT
    t1.Id1,
    t1.Id2,
    t1.Value1,
    t2.Value2
FROM Temp1 t1
LEFT JOIN Temp2 t2 ON t1.Id1 = t2.Id1 AND t1.Id2 = t2.Id2
ORDER BY t1.Id1
```

then plan is still optimal and use just `Merge Join` ([here](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rke1XXIlE) is xml):
[image]

So SQL Server know that output is ordered, however when I use window function, it do an extra sort. Why?

Behavior of `Table Spool`s is good explained [here](https://sqlserverfast.com/blog/hugo/2018/06/plansplaining-part-6-aggregates-with-over/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a database with COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL less or equal 110 (SQL Server 2012 (11.x)) the query works without SORT. Probably during the [improvement of SQL Estimator](https://cloudblogs.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2014/03/17/the-new-and-improved-cardinality-estimator-in-sql-server-2014/) some new bugs were added. If it is possible, you can change the compatibility level.

The [plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=BJCUY8LxN) of the query with COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 110

Comment: Good catch! I can confirm that on my SQL 2017 build, I do not see the extra Sort operator when running compatibility level 100 or 110; I do see it at higher compat levels.

Comment: So it sounds like a regression

Comment: Yes, I was able to get ideal plan (without `Sort`) with Compatibility Level up to 110, after that version it always add `Sort` operator to the plan

Answer (score 1):

Good question, and the short answer is that I expect this to be a bug. I was able to reproduce this on SQL Server 2017 (developer edition), RTM-CU12, build 14.0.3045.24 (with Trace Flag 4199 enabled).
I think you should post this repro to https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server (but label it as a bad optimization, not as a bug -- MS tends to read "bug" as "incorrect results" so by calling it a bug you run the risk of them closing it)

Longer answer with some background. A many to many Merge Join as used in this plan can only "fully" maintain order on one of the inputs (and I think it's the lower one, but have not yet done the work to prove it with 100% certainty). The data from the other input is stored in a worktable and re-used if the main table has a duplicate value. SO if one table has data 1,A / 1,B and the other has 1,C / 1,D; the result will be 1,A,C / 1,A,D / 1,B,C / 1,B,D. So the sort order of the second is not fully preserved.
However, for the purpose of this query nobody cares about complete preserving full sort order, we only care about the Id column. And the rewind logic in a many to many Merge Join does only happen for rows woth the same Id value. I guess we could call this partial order preservation: the guarantee of an order by Id (or in your example Id1, Id2) is maintained, but rows with the same value in those columns can be swapped around. So as you asserted, the output of Merge Join is definitely still guaranteed to be in order of Id1, Id2.
(In case you want even more background, here is the complete description of how I understand Merge Join to work: https://sqlserverfast.com/epr/merge-join/)

My first theory was that because of the above, the optimizer thinks that only one of the tables has its sort order preserved. That turns out to be incorrect. I get the exact same superfluous sort if I change the ORDER BY in the OVER specification to use t2.Id.

I did two more experiments: ORDER BY t2.Id1, t2.Id2; and ORDER BY t1.ID1, t1.Id2. And this is where it gets interesting. The last one (but ONLY the last one) gives me an execution plan without the extra Sort operator.

So my theory now is:

- If the required order after Merge Join is an *exact match* of the sort order of the input with complete order preservation, then no Sort is added.
- If the required order after Merge Join is an *exact match* of the sort order of the input with partial order preservation, then a Sort is added, even though it is not really needed
- If the required order after Merge Join is **NOT** an exact match of the sort order of any of the inputs, then a Sort is added - even if the required sort order is a subset of the existing sort order and hence implied and guaranteed.

BTW: Thanks for providing a full repro **AND** the complete XML query plan! That was very useful!

Comment: Commenting on my own reply because I suddenly realize that I missed that you create UNIQUE indexes at the end of your script, *and* I managed to mis-read the properties of the Merge Join. This is not a many-to-many Merge Join at all. (I feel bad now)

Comment: Yes it is just `LEFT OUTER JOIN`

Answer (score 0):

Well, the partitions need to be sorted as well to find the max per partition. If you were to change the code, like this, you won't see the extra sort in the exec plan.

```
SELECT
    t1.Id1,
    t1.Id2,
    t1.Value1,
    MAX(t1.Value1) OVER (PARTITION BY t1.Id1 ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS MaxValue1,
    t2.Value2
FROM Temp1 t1
LEFT JOIN Temp2 t2 ON t1.Id1 = t2.Id1 AND t1.Id2 = t2.Id2
```

Comment: When I run this query I do still get a Sort operator directly to the left of the Merge Join. And it does the same needless join on Temp1.Id1. Can you post what version of SQL Server you are using? There was another comment, now deleted, from someone who was not able to reproduce; that was on SQL Server 2017 and on a build older than what I have. So perhaps this is a regression?

Comment: @HugoKornelis , I am also not able to produce Sort,i am using sql 2012. My explanation is same.Better tell your sql server details.

Comment: @KumarHarsh my SQL Server details are in my answer. As you can see in the answer by Dzmitry, this behaviour appears to be introduced in SQL Server 2014.

Comment: On my SQL Server version (2016 13.0.4001) this `ORDER BY` doesn't help. It starts to use `HASH MATCH` instead, with additional `SORT` in different place

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server does not exhaustively attempt to avoid all logically unnecessary sorts. The logic required to do this would be complex and resource-consuming at compilation time.

Improvements have been made over the years to address the majority of common cases. This was detailed in a Microsoft response to a Connect item, but sadly that information has been lost to history now.

You can often help the ordering logic along by providing a top-level `ORDER BY` clause. In your particular case, the Merge Join preserves the order of the join keys (both of them), and the order required by the window function is a subset of that. We can avoid the sort by adding a final ordering requirement that matches the merge join:

```
SELECT
    t1.Id1,
    t1.Id2,
    t1.Value1,
    MAX(t1.Value1) OVER (PARTITION BY t1.Id1) AS MaxValue1,
    t2.Value2
FROM Temp1 t1
LEFT JOIN Temp2 t2 ON t1.Id1 = t2.Id1 AND t1.Id2 = t2.Id2
ORDER BY t1.Id1, t1.Id2; -- This is new
```

Execution plan (notice the sort has gone):

[image: plan without sorts]